# (This/That) Is being close or far relative, or does it have a rule?

Tags: this-that

Okay. Keeping in mind that I'm not talking about feelings or how much I like/dislike something, I'm asking about the usage of this & that regarding physical distance and objects. Must I stick to the rule that states if you can touch it, use "this", and if you can't, use "that."? please answer this question, and the next 2 questions.

1- A window at the end of the classroom keeps creaking/squeaking, can I say "someone closes THIS window please"?

​

​2- Is being near or far something relative that differs from a person to another?

I mean can I use "this" to what I personally consider close? That door is 5 meters away from me, but I consider it close, and I want to say this door. Or must I be able to touch without moving to use "this"?

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules. But a good rule of thumb is to use "that" if you have to point out which one. "this" will usually be close and distinct so it's obvious which is meant.

Comment: To answer your question about whether "this" and "that" differ from one person to another, if I am standing close to a window, and you are on the other side of the room, it will probably be "this window" if I mention it (even if I can't touch it) and "that window" if you mention it.

Comment: If there are two or more things and one is clearly closer than the others, then "this" is probably the closest, and "that" one of the farther away. If something's on the other side of the room, then "that" is probably more appropriate. But if you want to emphasise closeness, use "this", and vice versa. "That" can also be used for emotional distance e.g. when mocking a photo "look at that!" but "I like this". If you can provide a more precise example we might be able to help.

Comment: No, I wouldn't use _this_ for a window at the other end of the room.